# OIDC federated authentication issue in wso2 IS

Tags: wso2, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server, federated-identity

I am trying to do an OIDC federated authentication for a service provider in wso2 IS(local). The external identity provider which I am using is also a wso2 IS(external).

1. I have configured inbound auth configuration as below in my external identity provider(external):
   [image]
2. And in local wso2 I have configured identity provider as below and also done role mapping and claim mappings:
   [image]
3. Update the federated authentication for a service provider in local
4. when I try to access to the application which is federated, It redirects well to the external provider for authentication and after entering the credentials, I get the below error in headers and payload of browser.
   **Headers**:
   Request URL: Request URL: https://test-vm.com/?error_description=Authentication+required&error=login_required
   **payload**:
   error_description: Authentication required
   error: login_required
5. when I look at the logs of local wso2, I see the below error:

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler} - Authentication failed exception! javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

It seems SSL/TLS certificate presented by federated IDP can't be validated by local WSO2 IS.
You have to import the SSL/TLS certificate of federated IDP to the trust store of the local IS.

1. Export the public certificate from federated IDP's keystore

```
keytool -export -alias <alias_name> -keystore <keystore_name>.jks -file <public_key_name>.pem
```

2. Import the public key you extracted in the previous step to the client-truststore.jks file in local IS.

```
keytool -import -alias <alias_name> -file <public_key_name>.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass <keystore_password>
```